# Does the Aeron C Media Driver support Clustering capabilities?

Tags: c, udp, cluster-computing, hft, aeron

Previously I read in docs that the C Media Driver is in development and doesn't support Aeron Cluster like the Java Media Driver does.

Is this still the case? Is it a goal for C Media Driver to be on par with Java Media Driver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Aeron C Media Driver support Aeron Cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68326617/does-the-aeron-c-media-driver-support-aeron-cluster)

Comment: hi @Hasturkun that one is closed already editing and i can't reopen given my low reputation. So i create the new one after applying some editing based on review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Aeron C Media Driver does have the features to support Aeron Cluster. It also has the benefit of lower and more predictable latency when configured correctly plus access to extensions to provide transport encryption and reduced latency via ef_vi and DPDK native support.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that's a great news. However i can't find any documentations around this and is that an open source one in github?

Comment: What we document for open source is limited as we need to make a living and why we offer commercial support.

Comment: Thanks. I will have my team check about that.